# Обновления конкретного столбца в базе данных MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, sql

И меня есть строка в таблице:

```
   <tr data-id="5022" class="tr-border-top tr-border-bottom" style="height: 30px;">
      <td>Łukasz</td>
      <td class="cursor-pointer">Small business by the numbers</td><td>06-06-2021</td>
      <td><button class="odpowiedzButton buttonmoon">Odpowiedz</button></td>
      <td><button class="przekazButton buttonmoon">Przekaz</button></td>
      <td>
         <form action="services/zmiana_katalogu.php" method="post">Katalog: 
            <select class="buttonmoon" name="select">
               <option></option>
               <option>Odebrane</option>
               <option>Kosz</option>
               <option>Spam</option>
             </select>
             <input type="submit" name="katalog" id="katalog" class="buttonmoon zk" 
                    value="Zapisz">
          </form>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

По клику на кнопку `Zapisz`, предварительно выбрав нужный каталог из выпадающего списка у
меня должен обновится столбец с каталогом в базе данных в табличке.
Вот файл с обновлением ↓

```
<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "pocztadb";

                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }


                $select =  $_POST['select'];
                $sql_update = "UPDATE wiadomosci SET katalog = '$select' WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}";

                if ($conn->query($sql_update) === TRUE) {
                    
                
                } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                }

                    $conn->close();
                            // header("Location: ../poczta.php");

                ?>
```

И + вот скрипт ↓

```
    $(".zk").click(function(){
        $(this).load("services/zmiana_katalogu.php", { id: $(this).parent().parent().parent().data("id") });
    });
```

И у меня пишет следующие ↓
**Undefined array key "id" in** (`$sql_update = "UPDATE wiadomosci SET katalog = '$select' WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}";`), и я не понимаю как оно не может его получить, если я хочу одержать
его с помощью `$_POST`, может кто-нибудь подскажет что сделать чтобы исправить код?

Comment: Ну так у Вас в форме нигде не указан ID.

Comment: Он у меня в ```tr``` присутствует...

Answer (score 0):

Ваш ID должен быть в форме, а не в теге `<tr>`. `data-id` -> это для фронта, а не для сервера.

Один из вариантов решения проблемы - `<input type="hidden">`:

```html
<form action="services/zmiana_katalogu.php" method="post">Katalog:
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5022">
  <select class="buttonmoon" name="select">
    <option></option>
    <option>Odebrane</option>
    <option>Kosz</option>
    <option>Spam</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="katalog" id="katalog" class="buttonmoon zk" 
         value="Zapisz">
</form>
```

И в Вашем запросе в БД [SQL-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Вместо

```php
$select =  $_POST['select'];
$sql_update = "UPDATE wiadomosci SET katalog = '$select' WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}";

if ($conn->query($sql_update) === TRUE) {                         
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Используйте:

```php
$stmt= $conn->prepare("UPDATE wiadomosci SET katalog = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['select'], $_POST["id"]);

try {
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: А что означает ``"si"`` в строчке ```$stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['select'], $_POST["id"]);```

Comment: s -> string, i -> integer: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php